# Slider is working strange. Load two images at once - blogger page.

Tags: javascript, html, content-management-system, blogger

I made a little modification my blogger page. I changed font color. Easy stuff.

Unfortunately something gone wrong and now my slider is working strange. Load two images at once.

What can I do?

The amount of code is beyond me.

Page: https://noa-artpage.blogspot.com/

Code: http://pastebin.com/qSbrfggN

Comment: line 4689 - `function createSummaryAndThumb(pID,title,url,,comment,tag,author){` that's a probelm - your browser would have a **developer** *tools console* - that's how I found that error in 3 seconds :p

Comment: Line 5245 in your pastebin code page you gave a link to, remove the extra commer (,).